# jQuery Mobile with Phonegap version issue

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am a newbie to jQuery Mobile platform , I have developed a simple application in jQuery Mobile with Phonegap. It is successfully working in android API level 19 , but Some parts (Scrolling,datepicker etc.) are not working with lower android versions API 18 , API17 ..API 8,

I am currently using

```
css : jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css 
js  : jquery-1.10.2.min.js
js  : jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js

Phonegap : cordova-2.5.0.js
```

Can anybody suggest the .js files which supports at least API 8 , API 18, API 19 and also the Phonegap version to use along with them. I have seen many problems regarding the version issues for jQuery Mobile , Expecting some good suggestions :)

Answer (score 0):

Last year we developed an app with jquery mobile and we successfully test it on Android API level 7 (2.1) & upwards.

We used:

- jquery.mobile 1.1.0.css
- jquery.mobile 1.1.0.js
- jquery-1.7.2
- phonegap-2.0.0

And for the datepicker we used jquery.ui.datepicker.js.
Hope this helps :D

Comment: which was the phonegap version?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the phonegap version :P I edited the answer

Comment: Normally, higher versions have the new features and updates .. but here it is vice versa.. ANY SUGGESTIONS?

Comment: I would expect the newest version of jQuery mobile to be fully backwards compatible but apparently this is not the case. I didn't test the newest version on Android 2.x only on 4.x